# Alternate for Cookie in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm currently using cookie to store value via JavaScript in client side in IE6 older version

1. Is there is any other way to store values so that it can be retrieved when user navigates to different pages?
2. Is there a way to store values in the server via JavaScript without exposing a API in the server or any API which works in old and new browsers?
3. Is there a way to store values in a file via JavaScript?

Comment: My first question would be why you are trying to support IE6 or older? IE6 usage was under 1% in 2012 and I can't even find it on current stat sites, as the number is so low or non-existent.

Comment: *"store values in the server via JavaScript without exposing a API in the server"* - .... What?  I mean, you can certainly store data server-side, and the way you would interact with that data *via JavaScript* (and not via page post-backs and such) would be an API that you access with AJAX requests.  But if that's the goal then I don't understand the requirement of "without exposing an API".  What is the actual underlying problem you're trying to solve here?  It sounds like a random mixing of requirements that all prevent each other from working.

Comment: Is this related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72118584/ie6-version-file-or-session-localstorage-or-webstorage-is-not-supported#comment127443984_72118584)? Two questions about IE6 a couple of hours apart is too much of a coincidence.

Comment: @David local storage and web storage is not available in the IE6. Cookie is browser specific, the other user who logged in cannot have control. so looking for a centralized place where it can be saved in the server via a simple API

Comment: @techdev: So you want to store data server-side via an API "without exposing an API"?  That's certainly going to be... challenging.  But if you drop the requirement of "without exposing an API" then, yes, you can store data server-side and fetch it via AJAX requests and that will work in pretty much any browser.  So I guess the first thing you need to do is take a step back and define what it is you actually want to build.  Then you can build it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supporting IE6 is not a good idea; even if you are working on some legacy kiosk or something, get them to upgrade!

But to your answers:

1. No/Sortof -- the other way to do what you want is with localStorage, which was not introduced to IE until 8. You could redesign your app so that instead of different "pages" they are a single page web app; but that's no pleasure in IE6.
2. No -- For javascript to store values on the server, it needs to send data over the internet. When the client (your javascript in the browser) sends data to the server, that is, by definition, accessing an API. (I don't know what you mean by "or any api that works in old and new browsers" -- that clause doesn't make any sense to me.)
3. Maybe--but you don't want to. Javascript is prevented from accessing the local file system without explicit user permission, so you can't use the local filesystem to invisibly store data. That's what localStorage is for, but not available in IE6. If you want to explicitly save something as a file, with user choosing the file from a standard popup-window, that is not an easy process, especially in earlier browsers.

In short: I don't know why you're using IE6, and I don't know why you're not using cookies or an ajax call to the server, but those would be your best options.

Comment: Regarding 3, wasn't ActiveX available in IE6? I think this could access the filesystem directly.

Comment: Isn't ActiveX a huge security hole now though?

Comment: @Barmar — Default security settings block it.

Comment: @Barmar Activex is not enabled due to security issues